# MySQL: Truncate Table within Transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, truncate

I have an InnoDB table that needs to be re-populated every ten minutes within anywhere from 60k to 200k records. Our approach up to this point has been as follows:

1. Turn off Autocommit
2. Truncate the table
3. Perform Select Queries & additional Calculations (using PHP)
4. Insert new records
5. Commit

After the Truncate operation is performed though, the data is immediately deleted, and is no longer available from the User Interface. To our users, this has been pretty disconcerting, even though within about 30 seconds or so the script encounters the Commit operation and the table is repopulated.

I thought that perhaps I could wrap the whole operation, *including* the `Truncate`, in a transaction, and that this might cut down on the length of time during which the table appears empty to users. So I changed `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0` to `START TRANSCATION`.

**Yikes!** This had the opposite of the desired effect! Now the `TRUNCATE` operation still occurs at the beginning of the script, but it takes **much longer** to actually execute the `INSERT` operations within the transaction, so that by the time the `COMMIT` operation takes place and the data in the table is available again, it has been nearly ***ten minutes!***

What could possibly cause this? Truthfully, I wasn't expecting any change at all, because I was under the impression that initiating a transaction basically just turns off `Autocommit` anyway??

Answer (score 69, accepted):

A better way to accomplish this might be to insert the data into a new table, and then use [rename](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html) on both tables in order to swap them.  A single rename is all that's needed for the swap, and this is an atomic action, which means the users won't even be able to detect that it happened, except for the new data showing up. You can then truncate/delete the old data.

Comment: This is a really intriguing idea. My initial gut reaction was that it felt a bit hackish on the surface, but in fact theres a certain elegant simplicity to it and it would solve my problem perfectly. Wish I'd thought of it myself. :)

Comment: It's been nearly a year, just wanted to follow up and mention that this is what we ended up doing, and it works like a charm. We create the new table, insert a bucketload of records, and swap them out as soon as the update is complete -- to the end users it appears instant. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for this. Been wrestling with the best way to do a bulk data update without needing to take the DB down for a few seconds. This is a great workaround.

Comment: You may as well `DROP TABLE` on the old one after the rename.

Comment: We've used this approach in production for a while, using an atomic `RENAME table TO table_old, table_new TO table` and it worked perfectly. I had the same "this is hackish" feeling at first, but I could not see any downside to this approach.

Comment: Won't this affect the statistics of the table and any indexes? Do you need to run ANALYZE on it after?

Answer (score 77):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html

According to this URL, as of MySQL 5.1.32, `TRUNCATE TABLE` is DDL and NOT DML like DELETE. This means that `TRUNCATE TABLE` will cause an implicit `COMMIT` in the middle of a transaction block. So, use `DELETE FROM` on a table you need to empty instead of `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

Even `DELETE FROM tblname;` can be rolled back. It could take a while to rollback, so make sure InnoDB is properly tuned to handle the transaction time for such rollback possibilities.

Comment: That's excellent information, Rolando; I really appreciate the clarification (and the reference)! I'd absolutely have given you the Best if Kibbee hadn't given me such a brilliantly simple solution.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Notice that the difference between `DELETE FROM table` and `TRUNCATE table` is not in time of execution only. `TRUNCATE` resets also `AUTO_INCREMENT` value to 1, however `DELETE` does not.

Comment: "so make sure InnoDB is properly tuned to handle the transaction time for such rollback possibilities." Any insight on how to do this?

Comment: It's interesting to note that even a truncate operation causing an error (e.g. "truncate customers" if the table customers doesn't exist) could cause an implicit commit.

Answer (score 1):

From your description I can't really explain your time difference. The only thing that comes to mind is that you don't actually wrap the inserts into *one* transaction, but loop it.

The key difference with SET AUTOCOMMIT=0 is that if it's already 0, it won't do anything, where as with START TRANSACTION you will initiate a sub transaction within the current transaction.

Answer (score 1):

`TRUNCATE` implies `COMMIT` so that transaction is not an ACID transaction. This is noted above.

--

I use your approach in MySQL to emulate an `OUTER JOIN` of two tables by email address. The result stays in a table I can quickly `INNER JOIN` later.

Your approach is already having out-of-date data (since you require `DELETE`). So here is another approach which also uses out-of-date data, but foregoes transactions entirely. Less locking FTW.

Just `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and mark an "update time". At end of your script, `DELETE` anything with an old "update time".