# Transaction and Locking with multiple threads

Tags: c++, mysql, database, innodb

Hi All following is the problem scenario:

I am using MYSQL (Innodb engine), one of my application(C++/MYSQLCAPI) is doing following operation :

**START TRANSACTION**

**truncate my_table**

**load Data infile into table my_table.**

**if both the above command [truncate and load ] are successful then COMMIT**

**else ROLLBACK**

now another application(C++/MYSQLCAPI) which is reading this table in every second by following command.

**select * from my_table**

**ERROR: in this read attempt sometime it gets 0 data , what could be the reason for this ?**

Comment: I guess the reader gets no data because he tries to set a read lock (depends on isolation level) and doesn't get the lock because of your transaction. So he could try to reda with nolock.

Comment: no , reader application is not taking any lock .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
load `new` by whatever means
if something went wrong, don't do the next two steps.
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

This avoids the problem you mentioned, plus lots of other problems.  In particular, it needs no special transaction handling; the `RENAME` is atomic and very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing an empty table since [truncate table has an implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html). If you need to change the entire table in a transaction you can use delete then insert, or try the rename solution [presented in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5972404/28859)

Comment: Thanks a lot Broadbent for this  information. I am going to implement this solution now.