# Laravel tests don't rollback transaction after each test

Tags: laravel, testing, pdo, transactions, mariadb

My Tests are using the trait `RefreshDatabase` to "migrate fresh" before starting tests and use transactions for each testing method.

The migration works fine, but the transactions are not working at all.

I try to expose my setup:

- MariaDB 10.1 running in a docker container (I already proofed that all tables being used in my tests are in InnoDB, so transactions are supported)
- The base test class is using the `RefreshDatabase`
- I tried a separate connection for testing together with `$connectionsToTransact` and also using the default connection for testing. Transaction do not work either

My setUp method:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    Queue::fake();
}
```

You find the complete Test Class and Test base class in this Gist:
https://gist.github.com/patriziotomato/e25de1e160dace08edefa682b64bd150

I tried to debug already and also came down to PDO something starting and rolling back a transaction, so it seems like the laravel code attempt to transact and rollback, but it does not have any affect in my tests.

I need ideas what else could go wrong

Comment: Are you calling `setUp()` and `tearDown()` where needed?

Comment: Added my `setUp()` method to my original question

Comment: Are you developing a package? And why don't u use `sqlite` instead of a proper db?

Comment: I cannot use sqlite because my code include specific features that are not supported by sqlite

Comment: in this case I am not testing a package

Comment: Can you update your question and include one test method?

Comment: Updated my question and added a gist

Comment: Are you giving the db user the right privileges to remove & create tables

Comment: yes, since the usual migrations are all running under same user

Comment: There was a bug fixed in the latest version of Laravel 5.6 relating to `RefreshDatabase` in tests. Try upgrading to the latest version of 5.6

Comment: Which fix are you refering to?

Comment: @patriziotomato were you able to test a service that uses database transactions? while using the RefreshDatabase trait?

Comment: @anabeto93 at least the problem described above has been fixed in the meantime

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem. Never found the exact cause, but have a workaround - start and rollback transactions manually:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    DB::beginTransaction();
}

public function tearDown()
{
    DB::rollback();
    parent::tearDown();
}
```

Comment: In my case, i guess because of `RefreshDatabase` this does not work: `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue myself with a similar MySQL setup . I also tried Anthony's solution from above, and I saw the same `...1305 SAVEPOINT trans2 does not exist...` error just as well.

In my case the culprit was a `Model::truncate()` operation within the code (for a reimport command). Somehow that seems to have upset Laravel's transaction/rollback handling (or MySQL's?) resulting in the above error. Using `Model::all()->each->delete()` instead has solved my problem. (After some further testing, it seems I cannot reset the auto_increment value either, so that's where the problem must lie...)

> It is worth noting that it probably wouldn't have occurred with an in-memory database but with a MySQL setup for example if a rogue entry remains intact that could easily mess with the upcoming tests resulting in hard-to-debug errors, so just be careful... :)

**UPDATE**
The best answer [on this Laracast thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/db-transaction-doesnt-appear-to-rollback-properly) actually explains that the transaction operation has an implicit commit during the operation and that throws the transaction stack during testing.

Comment: It might depend on the Laravel version, but I don't think `Model::all()->each->delete()` would work. Specifically, `each` is a function that takes a callback, not a property, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using `Model::truncate()`.

Unfortunately `truncate()` is not "compatible" with transactions since MySQL 5.1.32. You can DROP the table but can't `truncate()` inside a transaction.

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/truncate-table.html
>
> According to this URL, as of MySQL 5.1.32, TRUNCATE TABLE is DDL and
>   NOT DML like DELETE. This means that TRUNCATE TABLE will cause an
>   implicit COMMIT in the middle of a transaction block. So, use DELETE
>   FROM on a table you need to empty instead of TRUNCATE TABLE.

Related answers from StackOverflow and Laracasts:

- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/db-transaction-doesnt-appear-to-rollback-properly
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5972738/667773

Comment: Denes you are a hero

Comment: Does `DELETE FROM` reset the ID column like truncate?

Comment: delete is compatible with transactions, only truncate is not compatible

Answer (score 1):

To rollback a transaction made in the your test files you could use `DatabaseTransactions`:

```
...
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
...

class SomeTest extends TestCase {

    use DatabaseTransactions;

public some_assertion_method()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi. RefreshDatabase does this as well but they don’t work in my case. I tried out your idea as well, but transactions don’t wanna work here :(

Answer (score -1):

I fix this bug creating these keys in phpunit.xml

```
</php>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
</php>
```

And using `RefreshDatabase.`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Change file phpunit.xml

```
<php>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysq"/>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="local"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SMS_DRIVER" value="array"/>
</php>
```

Add this trait to test file:

```
use DatabaseTransactions;
```